# How to send message automatically to a mobile number at scheduled time in IOS 8

Tags: ios, macos, xcode6.1, messageui

Here I am developing an app using IOS 8 in which i want to send text message after 2 hour  from current time. I tried to solve this using MFMessageComposeViewController and its delegate methods, but not able to schedule time and send message automatically.I google out this Issue but I don't get proper solution.Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to do this from the device.  The only way you can do this is to have your app send the message to a server and have the server send the text message at the appropriate time.